# How to programmatically set selected item of a dropdown list with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown, how to programmatically set selected value?

```
 <div class="dropdown chart-dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-sm border-0 dropdown-toggle p-50" type="button" 
         id="ddDataUsage" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         This Month
     </button>
     <div id="dd" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="ddDataUsage">
         <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="0">This Month</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="1">Last Month</a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried the below, but no luck

```
$('#dd').val('1');

let element = document.getElementById('dd');
element.value = '1';
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: You are doing wrong because it is a `div` element, not a `select` control. Can you show an HTML of a dropdown where one of the items *is* selected?

Comment: A `div` doesn't have a `value` property. Which library are you using to make that look like a dropdown list?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the data attribute as a selector to refer to the actual link. Then use an if statement to verify it exists, then simply add a class to that link stating its selected.

This is a very basic example without knowing more information.

```js
let sel = document.querySelector("[data-value='1']");
if(sel){
   sel.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected{color:red;}
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" data-value="1">Last Month</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" data-value="0">Next Month</a>
```

Comment: I try to avoid answering questions that aren't clear. We need to know what the OP means by selected before we can answer.